# how convert array to line with special flag

Tags: jquery

I need convert array to line use special flag on JQuery. Can you help me with this function, which do this?  Like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var arr=[];
var temp1=["test 1.1","test 1.2"];
var temp2=["test 2.1","test 2.2", "test 2.3"];
arr.push(temp1);
arr.push(temp2);
var str=SomeFunction(arr,"<&&>");
alert(arr);//show: "test 1.1<&&>test 1.2<&&>test 2.1<&&>test 2.2<&&>test 2.3"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the two arrays and then [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) like this:

```
var temp1=["test 1.1","test 1.2"];
var temp2=["test 2.1","test 2.2", "test 2.3"];
var arr = [].concat(temp1).concat(temp2);
alert(arr.join('<&&>'))
```

Calling `arr.push(temp1)` and `arr.push(temp2)` will create a 2 element array where each element is an array like this:

```
[[temp1],[temp2]]
```

Calling `[].concat(temp1).concat(temp2)` adds the elements inside `temp1` and `temp2` to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution with loops

http://jsbin.com/AvAj/1/

```
function SomeFunction(arr,sep){
  result="";
  for(var x1=0;x1<arr.length;x1++){
    for(var x2=0;x2<arr[x1].length;x2++){
      result += arr[x1][x2]+sep;
    }    
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I can not use loops, because the real code four dimensional array. It will be very difficult and cumbersome code.